# change colors in vector shapes - photoshop

Tags: javascript, photoshop, jsx

I have a problem with the code, which changes colors in vector shapes.

It works only on one layer and if you select more layers it pops error. Does anyone know how to fix it?

```js
#target photoshop
cTID = function(s) { return app.charIDToTypeID(s); };
sTID = function(s) { return app.stringIDToTypeID(s); };

function Action3() {

  function step1(enabled, withDialog) {
    if (enabled != undefined && !enabled)
      return;
    var dialogMode = (withDialog ? DialogModes.ALL : DialogModes.NO);
    var desc1 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var ref1 = new ActionReference();
    ref1.putEnumerated(sTID("contentLayer"), cTID('Ordn'), cTID('Trgt'));
    desc1.putReference(cTID('null'), ref1);
    var desc2 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var desc3 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var desc4 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc4.putDouble(cTID('Rd  '), 243);
    desc4.putDouble(cTID('Grn '), 110);
    desc4.putDouble(cTID('Bl  '), 93);
    desc3.putObject(cTID('Clr '), sTID("RGBColor"), desc4);
    desc2.putObject(cTID('FlCn'), sTID("solidColorLayer"), desc3);
    var desc5 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc5.putInteger(sTID("strokeStyleVersion"), 2);
    desc5.putBoolean(sTID("fillEnabled"), true);
    desc2.putObject(sTID("strokeStyle"), sTID("strokeStyle"), desc5);
    desc1.putObject(cTID('T   '), sTID("shapeStyle"), desc2);
    executeAction(cTID('setd'), desc1, dialogMode);

  };

  step1();      // Set
};

Action3.main = function () { Action3();};Action3.main();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should deselect all layers which are not shape layers. Or change layers one by one. (This is reason why CC library is so slow when you changing colors). Your code works for me if I have multiple shape layers, but all selected layers must be shapes and nothing else. Anyway there is bug in Photoshop which can remove your stroke options from all selected layers if one from layers doesn't has stroke.